# How do I declare classes in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop, object

How do I create a class in Javascript? Say I have this Customer, but I want to make another object from this Customer and change the name and such, how would I do this?

```
var Customer = {
        Name : "Frankie",
        PrintName : function(value)
        {
            alert(this.Name);
        }
    }
```

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have classes, but it has a sort of equivalent - so did you [look in Google](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=javascript+class)? If this is homework don't you have some sort of reference text?

Comment: Look up "JavaScript object constructor" in your favorite search engine.

Answer (score 1):

```
function Customer(name) {
    this.Name = name;
    this.PrintName = function () {
      alert(this.Name);  
    };
}

var customer1 = new Customer('Jake');
var customer2 = new Customer('Mike');
customer1.PrintName(); 
customer2.PrintName();
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is a prototypical inheritance language. You can emulate classic inheritance / oop with patterns such as listed here : http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html

Answer (score 0):

```
var Customer = {
        Name : "Frankie",
        PrintName : function() {
            alert(this.Name);
        }
    };
var AnotherCustomer = jQuery.extend({}, Customer, {Name: "Micha"});
Customer.PrintName();
AnotherCustomer.PrintName();
```

Comment: This doesn't work: it doesn't create another object based on Customer, it simply gets another reference to the existing object and changes its Name property. Add in `Customer.PrintName()` to the end of the above and you'll get "Micha", not "Frankie"...

Comment: sure it will work, but just with jQuery. See [example](http://jsfiddle.net/2bXea/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the John Resig (jQuery author) Simple Javascript Inheritance... [Take a look](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/)

It's very simple to use, [see](http://jsfiddle.net/fqRhM/3/).

Answer (score -1):

The language isn't like traditional object-oriented languages, but there are ways to get an object-oriented style in Javascript.  Many frameworks have helper functions for this, but the prototype system can be used directly as well.  A google search for 'javascript oop' should get you started.

Here, I'll give you the first link:  [Introduction to Object-Oriented Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript).