# javascript classes how to declare variable or how to include a constructor in a class definition

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am writing a class for date in javascript

i am trying to write a code like this

```
var bdate = {

    var today = null,

    //want a construction here

    init : function()
    {
        //this.today = some processing
    },

    isLesser : function()
    {

    }
}
```

Hope i have made my question clear in the code.

Can we do it in this style of code. what is it called as? classes in javascript or ... ?

besides, i have written classes not like this but like prototyping...

I have seen there are various ways to deal with classes in javascript and i have used but not sure why they should coded that way or their concept names.

So i always do trial and error and at one point it works and then i use that code.

**I want to know how to include a constructor in the above code.**

Suggestions please...

Comment: while i was searching for the answer i found another stackoverflow link which had a solution but i haven't experimented... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380772/how-do-i-declare-classes-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

I see you've answered your own question, but I highly recommend you use the [Date Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) built into Javascript and refrain from creating your own.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pattern I like to use:

```
(function(window){

  // Constructor
  function BDate(){
    this.today = new Date();
    // blah blah
  }

  // Object of methods, attached to the Bdate's prototype. You can think of these methods as instance methods.
  Bdate.prototype = {
    isLesser: function(){

    },

    isGreater: function(){

    }
  };


  // We're inside an anonymous function, so window has no access to our class. So, we assign the constructor function to a window var of the same name:
  window.BDate = BDate;
})(window);

// We can now use the class like so:
var myDate = new BDate(),
    herDate = new BDate();

myDate.isLesser();
herDate.isGreater();
```